# Angular login Authentication Error

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, observable

I am NEW to Angular. I am using this Angular method to user to log into the system.

```
loginuser(){
    const user = {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    };
    this.Auth.loginUser(user).subscribe((res)=>{
      if(res){
        this.Auth.storeData(res.token, res.user);
        this.flashMessage.show('You are Successfully logged In.', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 5000 });
        this.router.navigate(['/userProfile']);
      }else{
        this.flashMessage.show('You are Password or Username not Correct.', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 5000 });
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }

    });
  }
```

But I got a error in my VScode editor showing like this.
[image]

And my angular-cli also showing these errors.
[image]
But in my node function I clearly define those parameters. And this is my node function.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res)=>{
    const name = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    //console.log(password);
    User.findByName(name,(err, user)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user){
            res.json({state: false, msg:"No User Found"});
            //return false;
        }
        User.passwordCheck(password,user.password, (err, match)=>{
            if(err) throw err;

            if(match){
                const token = jwt.sign({User} , config.secret, {expiresIn:86400*3});
                res.json({
                    state: true,
                    token: "JWT" + token,
                    user:{
                        id:user._id,
                        name:user.name,
                        ID:user.ID,
                        IDexpDate: user.IDexpDate
                    }
                });    
            }else {
                res.json({state:false,msg:"password does not match"});
            }
        });

    });   
    console.log(password);
});
```

I am using Angular version 6 to develop this application. I search for this in many areas unfortunately I cannot find any problem like this. I think my service functions also will need to give an answer so this are my service files.

```
readonly baseURL ='http://localhost:3000/users/login';    
storeData(token,userdata){
    localStorage.setItem("tokenid",token);
    localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(userdata));
    this.authtoken = token;
    this.user= userdata
  }
  loginUser(user){
    let header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.append('Content-Type','application/json');

    return this.http.post(this.baseURL,user,{headers:header});
  }
```

But when I console.log those res.token and res.user that gives me values in my console log. My problem is why that vscode editor show me error like that. Thank you very much for you to give your valuable time to help me.

Comment: Try setting the type of your response `res` to type `any` like `this.Auth.loginUser(user).subscribe((res: any)=>{`

Comment: Yeah its works thank you can you explain why it happend?

Comment: `res` is an unknown object, so none of its properties are known. Since the typescript compiler doesn't know them, it throws error. By setting the type to `any`, the compiler knows that this object can contain any property. Therefore everything is allowed which can lead to runtime errors.

Comment: An other way to bypass compiler warnings is to use square brackets like this `res['token']`. The right way to do this is to create an interface, and parse your response to this interface, therefore, you would have no error, plus code completion for your api response.

Comment: Thank you @Ploppy But small question. when we call res['token'] is it create a interface to token value or any other thing happening?

Comment: Creating an interface will make it easier to code and prevent some errors, though it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you define in Node for response types doesn't carry over to your typescript.. you have to define it manually.

By referencing `resp.user` and `resp.token` Angular expects you to define your response to declare these objects. By setting `resp: any` you are telling Angular not to actually care to look for matching types.

If you always expect your response here to contain a user and token, it would be better to declare the response:

```
resp: {
user: string,
token: string 
}
```